# Google Maps фрагмент в Android клиенте

Tags: android, android-sdk, android-studio, google-maps-api

Есть ли возможность в обычное android приложение поместить карту **Google Maps** по нажатию на `Button`, при загрузке нового `Activity`, при этом не создавая приложение **Google Maps**? Если да, то можно дать развернутый ответ.

Answer (score 2):

Все понял, просто можно создать приложение Google Maps но использовать стандартные Activity, при этом сразу вызывать стандартное Activity, просто раньше не получалось